# Calculating Battery Charge from Solar Panel

Tags: arduino, batteries, solar-cell

I am trying to create an arduino system with radio-transmitters and radio-receivers. The system runs from a rechargable battery that is charged with a solar panel. I am using a **1.1W 6V solar panel**.

My problem is that I don't know how to make such a connection and I don't know what batteries to choose to power the arduino, assuming that I need it to run for **5-7 days** without solar power and that the solar panel is good enough to recharge the batteries while they power the arduino. We are also assuming that the solar panel has **8 hours of sunlight**.

To the arduino are connected the following sensors:

- **Flame Sensor**
- **Light Resistor x2**
- **Smoke Sensor**
- **Radio Transmitter**
- **Radio Receiver**
- **DHT11 Temperature & Humidity Sensor**

I am also looking to see if I can power down most sensors and power them on later if an event occurs. So probably all the sensors could be sleeping except the **DHT11** and the **Radio Receiver**. Preferably though, if at all possible, the rest of the sensors should be on, if we can handle **5-7 days *without* the solar panel**. I don't know if more information is needed but I'd be pleased to help out in the comments, or provide more information by editing the question. :)

Comment: Compute the power (watts) required by all the components - from datasheets - or measure it (with the relevant sensors on or off). Multiply by 120 to 168 (hours) to get the energy in watt-hours. If you're using switching regulators between battery and the device, add 25% or so. Or factor in the efficiency of your power supply. That gives your battery capacity in watt-hours. Divide that by the battery voltage; that's the amp-hours you need. (If you choose a lead-acid battery, double it; they don't like deep discharge. For other batteries, add 30 or 50%).

Comment: Do you need the Arduino to be ON all the time during 5 to 7 days? Or will I go to sleep? How many minutes per day it needs to be in active Mode.. and all other sensors as well need not be active all the time..

Comment: Are you expecting that solar panel to be bale to p over charge to the battery during those 5 to 7 days.. your statement is little contradicting.. **assuming that I need it to run for 5-7 days without solar power and that the solar panel is good enough to recharge the batteries while they power the arduino**

Comment: The arduino has to be up for 5-7 days. The solar panel is able to charge the batteries for 8 hours of sunlight every day. The batteries have to sustain themselves without the solar panel, so they are able to keep powering the arduino without being charged by the solar cell